# how do I select a node using css by decendant index?

Tags: css

given this html

```
<div>
  <span>foo <span foo="bar">bar</span></span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span foo="bar">select me only</span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
```

Currently I am selecting this "select me only" `span` with this javascript:
`document.querySelectorAll('span[foo=bar]')[1]`

How do I recreate this using a css selector only?

Something like `div span:nth-of-type(4)[foo=bar]` does not work because adding another `<span></span>` will break it.
I believe this is equivelent to the `.eq(1)` operator with jquery.

Comment: You can select it by custom attribute:

    `span[foo="bar"]:last-of-type`

Comment: that does not work

Comment: span ~span[foo="bar"]

Comment: I'm sorry, please clarify the question. Can you show an image of the final output you want to achieve?

Comment: I add an answer, please check if it's what your looking for.

Answer (score -2):

*Edited*

```css
div span[foo~=bar]:not(:last-of-type){
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>foo <span foo="bar">bar</span></span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span foo="bar">select me only</span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
```

*Additional*

Since there's no final value for *span* tag in the document and it's just random adding span tag with same attribute `foo="bar"`, it can't judge how to get this *select me only* on the span. And the author trying to figure it out how to achieve getting this *select me only* using an css only. So, since this question is need a deeper study and experimentation, For now, I only suggest giving his *span* a *key* so the system will know how to get or what to select in this nested span.

I come up with this thinking since even a person cannot judge to select without it's uniqueness like saying *That wallet is mine because it's color black*, but we all knew that many people have same wallet and same style, unless you have an ID/picture on that wallet that prove it is yours.

Finally, here I could suggest to add key on the specified span you are need to get.

```css
div :where(span[key~=unique]){
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>foo <span foo="bar">bar</span></span>
  <span>a</span><span foo="bar">b</span></span>
  <span>c</span><span foo="bar">d</span></span>
  <span foo="bar">bar</span></span>
  <span foo="bar">bar</span></span>
  <span foo="bar" key="unique">select me only</span>
  <span foo="bar">
    <span foo="bar">wrw</span>
      <span foo="bar">gd</span></span>
    </span>
    <span foo="bar">rr</span></span>
  </span>
  <span foo="bar">ddww</span>
  <span foo="bar">xqwr</span></span>
  <span foo="bar">sdw</span></span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is incorrect, add a   <span foo="bar"></span> under the select me only and it will select both. I only want to select the first

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't help. I edit my answer.

Comment: Maybe someone will give you the best answer. So for now, if possible, I suggest you to give a key for your span.